# Disable identity check for a certificate in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, certificate, identity

I have a transport-security connection with anonymus client.
I have a wildcard-certificate on the server and its not always sure that i know the hostnames where the services are running.

Is there any possibility to disabe the identity check for the certificates in a wcf connection?

I tried to work with the CustomIdentityVerifier. I set this verifier in the SslStreamSecurityBindingElement but this has no effect...
When i try it with a custom binding it works fine.

Is there another point, where i have to switch the CustomIdentityVerifier?

Comment: Could you provide the custom binding that is working?

Comment: Yes it works with a custom binding, but i dont know if i create a custom binding from my original NetTcpBinding, that the custom binding act exactly the same as my original binding.

Comment: Please show the custom binding, maybe it helps to identify the difference.

Comment: Hi nodots, thx for your help. We go with the CustomBinding :-)